# how can i change a nested object 'property value' in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I want when the user start typing inside a input field age `from` and `to` property value to get update so i can send the information to the backend.

my `onBlur` eventhandler dosen't work i get a `undefiend: 43(user typed num for exam)` property outside of `age object` on my state;

code

```
  const [advancedSearch, setAdvancedSearch] = useState({
    selectIdentify: "",
    type: "",
    gender: "",
    age: { from: "", to: "" },
  });

==========================
                   <TextField
                    label="Age From"
                    type="number"
                   onBlur={(e) =>
                      setAdvancedSearch((data) => ({
                        ...data,
                        ["age"["from"]]: e.target.value,
                      }))
                    }
                  />
                  <TextField
                    label="Age To"
                    type="number"
                   onBlur={(e) =>
                      setAdvancedSearch((data) => ({
                        ...data,
                        ["age"["to"]]: e.target.value,
                      }))
                    }
                  />
```

Comment: {...data,{age : ...age,to:e.target.value}}

Comment: You're creating a new object, so it should be `{...data, age: {...data.age, from: e.target.value}}`